# How to make a file and its parent directory at once?

Tags: linux, bash

I used `touch` to make a file and its parent directory at once, but failed,

```
$ touch ./base/data/sounds/effects/camera_click.ogg
touch: cannot touch `./base/data/sounds/effects/camera_click.ogg': No such file or directory
```

How to do?